# CSS Strikethrough price with space

Tags: css, woocommerce, text-decorations, strikethrough

I am using woocommerce and want to display the original prices as a price tag with a strikethrough (when products are on sale).

The problem is now that woocommerce adds a space between the currency and the price amount, which I cannot change. When I use `.amount{ text-decoration: line-through;}` the line goes only through the text but not through the space between them. I want to display one line through everything.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

I tried this using `border-bottom: 1px solid;` but the problem is that it's not possible to add some kind of negative padding...

Anyone got an idea how to solve this css issue? Actually it's a really small problem but I was not able to find a solution after a long time of research.

*Edit*:

This is the HTML/CSS sourcecode which I am using:

**HTML**

`<p class="deals-value"><span><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">CHF</span>157.00</span></span></p>`

**CSS**

`.deals-value .amount {text-decoration: line-through;}
.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol {margin-right: 10px;}`

Please find the full html/css source and website here: https://prnt.sc/hmfatr

Comment: can you show code, this can be achieved with pseudo element. With code i can help you ;)

Comment: Share your sample code.

Comment: If you can share the html and css, it will be better to give some exact solution.

Comment: I added a screenshot with the html/css source. Hope this helps - many thanks in advance for so many answers :)

Comment: Sorry I thought it would be easier if you can see the whole code and related website @Alohci please have a look at the updated question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `:after` pseudo element, absolutely positioned over the text, something like this:

```
.amount{ 
  position: relative;
}
.amount::after{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

If you shared your HTML/CSS I could be more specific with the styling, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: I wrote a Sass mixin to do this kinda thing a while back if it's of use: http://alexplummer.com/article/code-snippets/better-looking-text-decoration.html

Comment: Your bottom isn't responsive though, what if a user suddenly zooms in? Or the font size gets changed dynamically?

Comment: @Roberrrt as I said, it's hard to be more specific without being given any HTML/CSS, but generally that would be easily accounted for with a % based position and/or transform: translateY. I didn't really want to fixate on styling the :after when that wasn't really the question, but I'm happy to provide OP with more information if they need it.

Comment: @delinear Many thanks for your input. I tried it by adding your css code to the classes `span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount::after` and `span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount ` but this does not work because these classes are used also for the original price. I need to assign it to `.deals-value` but I couldn't get it working. Another problem is that the same price (.deals-value) is displayed on another site in another font-size  and so the line-through position is not correct anymore. 

You can find the source code in the edited original question. Many Thanks!

Comment: @Nicola you should be able to do `.deals-value span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount::after` and `.deals-value span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount`, does that not work? As for the position, as I mentioned above, if you need it responsive for different font sizes, try `bottom: 50%` or `bottom: 0; transform: translateY(-50%)` and see if that helps?